# Using reduce to delete even numbers in an object

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

I'm given an array of numbers. I have created an object named counts, whose keys are the numbers and values the amount of times those numbers appear in the array. Can't work out how to use reduce to delete the even counts of the numbers.

```
A =  [ 20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5 ]

n =  5

function findOdd(A) {

  let counts = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    let num = A[i];
    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
  }

//counts -> { '1': 2, '2': 2, '3': 2, '4': 2, '5': 3, '20': 2, '-1': 2, '-2': 2 }

  const answer = Object.keys(counts).reduce((object, key) => {
    if (key % 2 !== 0) {
      object[key] = counts[key];
    }
    return object;
  }, {})

  return answer;
```

Must return the key of the odd count.

SOLUTION:

```
function findOdd(A) {
  const counts = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    let num = A[i];
    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
  }
  Object.keys(counts).forEach(key => {
    if(counts[key] % 2 === 0) {
    delete counts[key];
    }
  });
  return Number(Object.keys(counts));
}
```

Comment: Can you show some example input and output please?

Comment: If it's an array of numbers, why not a simple `filter()`?

Comment: The code returns an array with key/value pairs with counts of the odd numbers. What is the error/problem?

Comment: You should provide your data when asking a question. From the code it looks like this is a multi-dimensional array with members that are all as long as the array that contains them?

Comment: How would I filter and get the count of each number? I created the object so the keys would be the number and the values would be the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function findOdd(arr) {
  const counts = {}; // `const` declared objects/arrays are not immutable
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    counts[arr[i]] = counts[arr[i]] || 0;
    counts[arr[i]]++;
  }
  Object.keys(counts).forEach(key => {
    if(counts[key] % 2 === 0) {
      delete counts[key];
    }
  });
  return counts;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 9];
// 1:3, 2:1, 3:1, 4:3, 6:1, 9:1
// Does not show a `5` key due to there being an even number of fives in `array`

console.log(findOdd(array));
```

Yes, I know `delete` is inefficient, but that shouldn't matter, unless it is a requirement for being quick. I believe you can just set `counts[key] = undefined` or `counts[key] = null`, you can see the benchmarks [here](https://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/16)

Comment: Used everything from Object.keys() down. Had to return Number(Object.keys(counts)); rather than just counts. Thanks very much

Comment: @benelliott87why `Number()` ? That won't work if there are more than one item which has an odd count.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Object.entries` to obtain entires, then `filter` entries whose values are odd, and then reconstruct new Object from those entries using `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const countObject = { '1': 2, '2': 2, '3': 2, '4': 2, '5': 3, '20': 2, '-1': 2, '-2': 2 };
const oddEntries = Object.entries(countObject).filter(([key, value]) => value % 2 !== 0);
const oddCountObject = Object.fromEntries(oddEntries)

console.log(oddCountObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already great answers but as the question said "using reduce" I thought it'd be fun to try doing this using only `reduce`:

```
const findOdd = arr => arr.reduce((acc, d, i, list) => {
    if (!acc[d]) {
        acc[d] = 0;
    }

    acc[d]++;

    if (i === list.length - 1) {
        return Object.keys(acc)
            .reduce((subAcc, key) => ({
                ...subAcc,
                ...(acc[key] % 2 === 0 ? {} : {
                    [key]: acc[key]
                })
            }), {})
    }
    return acc;
}, {})
```